# jquery class selector not including element with specific parent

Tags: jquery, css, selector

**HTML:**

```
<div class="abc"> ... </div>
<div class="abc"> ... </div>
<div class="abc"> ... </div>
<div class="abc"> ... </div>
<div id="specificParent">
   <div class="abc"> ... </div>
</div>
```

In my jquery I want to remove all the contents of `.abc` div except for the last abc. How can I write selector for this ?

**jQuery:**

```
$(".abc, :not(#specificParent .abc)").html("");
```

The above jquery does not work. It is just to convey what I meant. I need help to form a proper working selector.

Comment: If the other `.abc` share a common parent, the `E > F` format [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) seems like the simplest (and probably best performing) option, for example `$('body > .abc').html('')`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(":not(#specificParent) > .abc").empty();
```

---

#### EDIT

I imagine this might not be the most efficient selector, performance-wise. An alternative method would be to filter it out manually;

```
$(".abc").filter(function () {
    return this.parentElement.id !== "specificParent";
}).empty();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aFm7T/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -  Demo -->  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/55JSE/

```
$(".abc:not('#specificParent .abc')").html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(".abc").not('#specificParent .abc').html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all '.abc' whos parent not '#specificParent':

```
$("*:not(#specificParent) > .abc")
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4WeK4/